# SQL query to add start and end date for a between two rows based on the input

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named Acount has following structure

```
  acc_id      name       value   phase   date

    1         acc_type   trial   start    t1
    1         name1      value1  phase1   t2
    1         acc_type   trial   end      t3
    1         name2      value2  phase2   t4
    1         acc_type   trial   start    t5
    1         name3      value3  phase2   t6
    1         name4      value4  phase4   t7
    1         acc_type   trial   end      t8
```

Table is sorted based on the date

What I want is to add two column `start_date` and `end_date` and update the column for a particular pair of phase value `start and end` where `name` is `acc_type` and `value` is `trial`.

So output will look like:

```
acc_id      name       value   phase   date    start_date    end_date

    1         acc_type   trial   start    t1      t1          t3
    1         name1      value1  phase1   t2      t1          t3
    1         acc_type   trial   end      t3      t1          t3
    1         name2      value2  phase2   t4      
    1         acc_type   trial   start    t5      t5          t8 
    1         name3      value3  phase2   t6      t5          t8
    1         name4      value4  phase4   t7      t5          t8
    1         acc_type   trial   end      t8      t5          t8
```

I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Is your acc_id is same ?

Answer (score 2):

This is complicated, because you need to partition by the starts and ends.  If I assume that the proper ordering is the dates, then you can use cumulative `max()`:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when phase = 'start' then date end) over
           (partition by acc_id order by date) as start_date,
       max(case when phase = 'end' then date end) over
           (partition by acc_id order by date) as end_date
from t;
```

EDIT:

I notice that there are values "in-between".  This requires more complex logic.  The idea is to count the net number of starts and ends, and to use this for filtering:

```
select t.*,
       (case when netstartend > 0 or phase in ('start', 'end')
             then max(case when phase = 'start' then date end) over
                      (partition by acc_id order by date)
        end) as start_date,
       (case when netstartend > 0 or phase in ('start', 'end')
             then max(case when phase = 'end' then date end) over
                      (partition by acc_id order by date)
        end) as end_date
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when phase = 'start' then 1 when phase = 'end' then -1 else 0 end) over
                 (order by date) as netstartend
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: result is not coming as expected. start_date looks good but end_date is not coming as required. thanks.                                                You can check on this link   "http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/36a3b/1"

Comment: I am checking your edited answer. I will let you know the results. Thanks a lot. Above comment was for your first solution.

Comment: Still not coming what is expected. start_date is coming perfect but end_date is not correct. could you please look into that.  thanks .

Comment: @Rajeevkumar: would you supply a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for the problem you're experiencing? It's better than asking Gordon to do all your work `:-)`

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: It worked for me. little change was required in case of end_date. i used MIN in stead of MAX and used order by date desc.. Then it worked . Thanks a lot for the query.